# Reading TCP/IP Socket Stream with an unknown byte size C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to receive a stream from a server via TCP/IP Socket connection and the length of the response is not always known.

The method in which I'm receiving to end is the following:

```
                    string resp = "";

                    do
                    {
                        bytesRec = clientSender.Receive(bytes);
                        resp += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    }
                    while (bytesRec != 0);
                    
                    return resp;
```

But two weird things occur,

1. when it looks to do a second receive, it takes about 5 seconds for the server to respond. I know this is code related as when I use a 3rd party terminal to communicate, this delay doesn't happen
2. when I get to the end of the stream (byteRec == 0), something happens to the socket and I can longer send req through. I have to disconnect and reconnect (which wouldn't be an option because it requires a logon packet to be sent prior to sending requests)

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: If you have a terminal then it means you are using text.  So read until end of line character '\n'.

Comment: TCP streams are just a stream of bytes.  The server has to document the protocol for the stream (how to interpet the bytes).  Also, a  response of zero means the stream was closed which is why you have to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Any advice on the latency when using .Receive()? First read is always really fast, if I put a Thread.Sleep() and a huge buffer, I can get most of what I need but this doesn't seem to be a reliable solution, especially if the response is going to be huge.

Answer (score 0):

Easer way is use TcpClient.

```
string resp;
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect("hostname", 21);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
if(tcpClient.Connected)
    resp = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); //or streamReader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I just want to add that both `TcpClient` and `StreamReader` are disposable objects, therefore you should put them in `using` statements to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using ReadToEnd() actually yields the same latency issue.